# Cannot change the background color of JFrame ContentPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, contentpane

So I have a snake program in java, works perfectly, however in my Frame class I cannot change the background color of my `JFrame`'s content pane, I use `getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);` but it is not working, any help ?

Here is my `Frame` class:

```
package mainpackage;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Frame() {

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK); \\NOT WORKING !!
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Snake by Sarp~");
        setResizable(false);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));


        Screen s = new Screen();
        add(s);

        pack();

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));
```

With the above layout manager, any component(s) you add to the frame will completely cover the content pane.

```
Screen s = new Screen();
add(s);
```

You may set the background of the content pane, but then you add a component to the content pane. So you will see the color of the `Screen` component over top of the content pane.

Set the color of your Screen object to be whatever you want:

```
s.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
```

Comment: @YoungMillie, that is my point. He adds a component of top of the content pane.